# Fetch the source code from wsp in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package

I need to fetch the source code from wsp in SharePoint 2010.
I am having the wsp file and i can converted it to a caqb file and opened this zip and extracted it. so i got the DLL.

But how to see the ascx file's cs file - source code- within this wsp

Comment: Use reflector or ilspy.

Answer (score 1):

Now you need to decompile the dll files using any of the tools available. I personally prefer JetBrains dotPeek, which is free for download from jetbrains web site.

Help document: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/2016.2/dotPeek_Getting_Started.html

Comment: am unable to download the jetbrains :  getting the below errors: Can't download from https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.LightInstaller.exe

Can't download to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\JetPackages\\JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.LightInstaller.exe

Unable to connect to the remote server
   at JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Bootstrap.Runs.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Main>b__a(